# How to return multiple mime-types to web-client in one Http Response

Tags: javascript, python, http, web, bokeh

How can I respond to an Http Request with data in multiple mime types in the same Http Response e.g. static Bokeh html and plot metadata in json.

Comment: HTTP wasn't built for that.  When a client requests a resource, it expects at most one resource back.  If you want to send multiple resources, trigger multiple requests.

Comment: The below answer works. Plus I know of websockets and multipart responses https://anentropic.wordpress.com/2010/05/14/jsdjango-streaming-multi-part-ajax-responses-mxhr/

Comment: The answer below is combining everything into one resource with one MIME type.  If that's the answer, then the question is misleading.

Comment: true if you have better please post and i will gladly accept

Comment: That is the question I asked before I knew anything and it stands a good question. If anything you should flag the answer although there too your reasoning is questionable.

Comment: The answer is an attempt to answer the question; IMO it doesn't merit a flag (or even a downvote).  It should, however, mention that it's a workaround, rather than what was explicitly being asked for.  (And an explanation of why it has to be a workaround, would help as well.)  Answer the question as thoroughly as you would if someone else had asked it.

Answer (score 0):

JSON can hold html as a value so one can Http Respond with JSON and extract the values in the client [I don't know if this works for images and files].

Here is an example sending Bokeh html with python [works in a server-side Django app and JQuery ajax client]

client

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/yeast_liquid_plates/growth_graphs/',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(pp.saved_cells),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        console.log(result['json']);
        $div_plot.empty();
        $div_plot.append(result['html']);
    }
});
```

server

```
def growth_graphs(request):
    script, div = components(figure1, CDN)
    r = {}
    r['html'] = script+div
    r['json'] = {'blue': 'yoohoo'}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(r))
```